# Problem publishing ASP.net web application on University server

Tags: iis, asp.net

HI, I am doing my undergraduate project. I need to publish it on university server. I was given a space(ftp), login, password. I have done all the steps when publishing it e.g throw visual studio or absolute ftp. I am getting error "Server Application unavailable" when trying to access it. 
Our technician is not good at Microsoft "stuff", I believe that it is something to do with IIS on the server. But I have no idea. I looked online it only tells about IIS on developer's machine(how to configure), but how to do it on server? what I have to tell my technician? cause he won't reserach himself(( Thank you! any source are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To run an ASP.Net website depending on the version of IIS running on the server the following is required:

**Windows Server 2003 (IIS 6)**

- ASP.net application must be enabled under the third party extensions
- The site needs to be created with an Application Pool configured to the right ASP.Net Version (1.1,2.0,4.0)
- The default.aspx page must be added to the valid index pages settings.

**Registering ASP.Net**
If the above has been done you need to register the version of ASP.Net on the server for it to work. This can be done via the command line by running

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework[Framework Version]\aspnet_regiis.exe /ia

**Windows Server 2008 (IIS 7/7.5)**

- The .Net Role needs to be enabled. (Server Roles)
- The ASP.net Role needs to be enabled. (Server Roles)
- The site needs to be created with an Application Pool configured to the right ASP.Net  Version (1.1,2.0,4.0)
- The default.aspx page must be added to the valid index pages settings.

This is a top level overview of what needs to be done. The IIS 7 and higher pretty much self configures most of these when the role is installed. Based on the error your describing it seems like the **Application Pool** has not been configured or it is set to the wrong version of ASP.Net.

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur for number of reasons. The first thing to do is get the technician to check the Windows Event log for any errors, as this will give a more detailed explanation of what the problem may be.

Once you've have a more detailed error you can take a look at Diago's list and see which setting is the likely cause. The most common reason I see this error is because the site is set to use the wrong .net version (1.1 or 2)

Comment: +1 for referring to my list and confirming my suspicions.